# dynamically add and remove formGroup in angular 2 custom child component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have a custom switch that needs to be used for both with and without `forms`.
i.e.

**custom-switch.component.html**

```
<div class="custom-switch" [formGroup]="parentGroup">
    <input id="{{ id }}" name="status" type="checkbox"
           [checked]="checked"
           formControlName="{{ switchName }}"
           (change)="onChange($event, id)" />
    <label for="{{ id }}" class="label-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-selector="true"
           data-title="Switch"></label>
</div>
```

**custom-switch.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector : 'custom-switch',
    template : 'custom-switch.component.html'
})
export class CustomSwitchComponent {
    @Input('id') id : any = 'switch';
    @Input('parentGroup') parentGroup : any;
    @Input('switchName') switchName : any;

    onChange() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

from parent component i call the component for form child component as:

```
<custom-switch [parentGroup]="form" [switchName]="'switch'"></custom-switch>
```

I want to use:

```
<custom-switch></custom-switch>
```

and remove

`[formGroup]="parentGroup"` and
`formControlName="{{ switchName }}"`

for non form child component.

**How could i dynamically remove `formGroup` and `formControlName`? As it generates error when i try to use it on non form components.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to conditionally add/remove bindings. Only the addition of attributes to the DOM can be controlled by conditions.

You can use `*ngIf` to switch between two elements where one has the binding and the other doesn't have one:

```
<custom-switch *ngIf="useForm" [parentGroup]="form" [switchName]="'switch'"></custom-switch>
<custom-switch *ngIf="!useForm"></custom-switch>
```

Comment: So there is no way other than using the `<template></template>`  for the whole chunk of html to replace [formGroup]="parentGroup"?? Also i have edited the last part for your better understanding, i suppose you got mislead by my last part. Although the solution might be same.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `<template></template>`. If it is to use a single `*ngIf` for a bunch of elements, I'd use `<ng-container *ngIf="..."></ng-container>` because it allows to use the same `*ngIf` syntax as on normal elements, while `<template>` requires `<template [ngIf]="...">`. `<ng-container>` also isn't added to the DOM.

Comment: And no, I don't think there is another way to accomplish that. `formGroup` is used as directive selector and they only work if added statically.